# B+ Tree first insert

Tags: java, algorithm, b-tree

I am trying to implement B+ tree in java. I am confused if the first insert is saved only in the leaf or there are 2 entries i.e. one in root, pointing to the leaf and one in leaf(with data pointer).

If i try to enter it in both, i will have 2 leaf node that will be almost empty.

If i just enter it in leaf, my root will be of type leaf. I am not sure if root can be of type leaf.

```
public class BTree {
    private BTreeInnerNode root;
    private int fanout = 3;
    public BTreeInnerNode getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public BTree(int fanout) {
        this.fanout = fanout;
    }

    public BTree(){
        root = new BTreeInnerNode(fanout);
    }
}
```

Node

```
public class BTreeInnerNode extends BTreeNode {
    public BTreeNode[] children;
    public BTreeInnerNode(int fanout){
        super(fanout);
        nodeType = NodeType.Node;
        children = new BTreeInnerNode[2*fanout];
    }
}
```

Leaf

```
public class BTreeLeafNode extends BTreeNode {
    public int[] rid;
    public BTreeLeafNode(int fanout) {
        super(fanout);
        nodeType = NodeType.Leaf;
        rid = new int[(2*fanout)-1];
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: shouldn't all nodes be type Node?

Comment: I have a base class for Node and Leaf, as they both have something in common, but Node will store the pointer to next node or leaf, and leaf will just store record id, so i created 2 subtypes

Comment: every node will have a value, and if the "NextNode" is null then it is a leaf. you don't need two subtypes

Comment: @Steve a leaf node and an inner node in B+ are conceptually different- one of them stores actual data with the other stores a set of keys. Although in this particular implementation the data itself is used as key I think it is better to keep the types different.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev it doesn't really matter, the data inside each node can either represent the "actual" data or the key depends on if it has more children. This will make insert much easier since you don't need to convert types every single time

Comment: @Steve yeap, but on the  other hand when you try to convert the B+ tree to something that is actually useful you will need significant refactoring if you go the route you suggest. After all B+ trees are mostly useful for handling huge data e.g. in filesystems and databases.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I remember I had to code a B+ tree for my university assignment. And all I used is one Node class with all the value/key shifting. I believe OP is doing a school assignment too since he could have just used an existing implementation instead of coding his own if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

In B+ data entries are only stored in leafs and the inner(non-leaf) nodes only store keys. Whether you allow the root itself to be leaf is your call, but I think the implementation will be slightly easier if the root is never a leaf node and upon the first insert, you create an successor leaf node. It seems in your implementation the data and the key are the same thing and that is what is causing the confusion. Still I recommend you consider these two different things - the values in the inner nodes are "keys" and the values in the leafs are "data". This will make it easier to change your B+ tree to store different things.

Comment: If i make them different, and i insert first key as 10, root will hold 10, the right pointer will hold ref to the leaf that have keys >= 10, and for now the leaf will hold just 10, but there will be a left leaf for keys <10, which will be currently empty, so is it correct for me to have 2 leafs with just one record